# Finding the mean and Std Dev from Geometric probability

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Wasn't sure what to call this.. .But here goes I am having trouble solving the following questions, here is the first, and how I have gone about it

`The daily probability of sighting a landscape bird near the lake is 0.3. What is the probability that the next sighting occurs five days from now?`

Using Geometric Probability

[image: Geo prob formula]

I (think this is correct) can calculate like so, the first question,

P(X=5) =[image]

This yields the result of `0.07203` where `P(X=5)` which I think is correct.

However my main problem is the question after it which is,

`What are the mean and standard deviation of the time until the next landscape bird is seen?`

So my question is how can I calculate the mean and standard deviation using the information I have? I am used to calculating it from a graph or table of statistics...

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Just use the formula for P(X = x) in the formula for mean and std. deviation and simplify.

Comment: I don't understand what formula, i have no values other than the ones in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably expected to use standard formulas for the mean and variance of the geometric distribution, and not to **derive** these formulas.

If the probability of "success" is $p$, and $X$ is the number of trials until the first success, then
$$E(X)=\frac{1}{p} \qquad\text{and}\qquad \text{Var}(X)=\frac{1-p}{p^2}.$$
In our case, $p=0.3$. Recall that you are asked for the standard deviation, so you will have to take the square root of the variance.

**Remark:** I have not checked the arithmetic, but your setup for the first question is correct.

Comment: Ah thank you, this is very clear, cheers

Comment: You are welcome. As I wrote, you are probably expected to *use* standard formulas for the mean and variance, and not to *derive* them. Derivation of the formula for the mean is quite straighftorward. Derivation of the formula for variance is more complicated/