# Are there multiple formulas for expected value/mean of geometric distributions?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

In class, I learned that the expected value for a geometric distribution is

> $E(X) = \frac {1-p}{p}$

where $p$ is the probability of success on any given trial, and $1-p$ is the probability of failure.

Online, ([Crash Course](https://youtu.be/5VMTeBoEcQg?t=300) and [Stack Overflow](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492241/finding-the-mean-and-std-dev-from-geometric-probability)) I am finding

> $E(X) = \frac{1}{p} $

I feel like each formula would yield different results so I am confused about which one to use. Am I missing a concept here, or are all these formulas acceptable to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are two conventions, depending on whether you count the number of trials (including the first success) or the number of failures *before* the first success.  But the variance is the same no matter which of the two definitions you use because the random variables differ by a constant (1).  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) describes both.